# Got fatal error during xfer (setuid failed) - Backuppc cygwin rsyncd

Tags: cygwin, backup, windows-server-2008-r2, rsync, setuid

I am trying to implement rsyncd (through BackupPc) on a Windows 2002R2 server which already has cygwin on it (for accessing mail logs). I normally use a lighter installation with just the cygwin1.dll and rsyncd.exe plus the config files (rsyncd.conf, rsyncd.lock, rsyncd.log & rsyncd.secret) and install as a service so that it can be triggered by my remote BackupPc server but that approach doesn't work here as the server already has a cygwin installation.

I installed the rsycd package through the cygwin installation, set it up as a service (following this [guide](http://wiki.nikoforge.org/Configuration_of_the_rsyncd_Service_on_a_Windows_Server)) and configured it to work with my BackupPc server.
Pings from the server are okay and I know it passes authentication (as I originally has the path to rsyncd.secrets wrong) but now it presents me with the error:

```
2014-06-26 13:03:01 full backup started for directory cDrive
2014-06-26 13:03:01 Got fatal error during xfer (setuid failed)
2014-06-26 13:03:06 Backup aborted (setuid failed)
```

The user is privileged and I have not received this error with the light installation method (mentioned above) in the same OS environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I could not get around the setuid error however I found a different implementation that allows me to achieve the same results with my systems.

[Here](http://urkomasse.blogspot.com.au/2012/10/using-backuppc-with-windows-server-2008.html) is the guide that I followed.

The crux of this solution involves using DiskShadow in conjunction with Rsyncd and it requires Diskshadow Scripts to run as part of the backup process.